# Linking Gridview hyperlink column to a url

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, hyperlink

First of all, let me say that I am very new to asp.net. I have been working in Winforms for quite some time now and I have done no programming with asp.net.

So please excuse me for my lack of knowledge.

Let me explain the scenario.

I have a gridview with a hyperlink column that when clicked should execute a method (e.g. DownLoadCustomerInfo(string CustomerID) )

How do I create a url for this column that the application should navigate to when the hyperlinked column is clicked.

I have read a number of posts that explain how I can navigate to another page. I don't need to do that.

I need to execute a method (DownLoadCustomerInfo as mentioned above).

Any help would be appreciated. Please help me by pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Nomad

UPDATE

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="file_name" DataTextField="file_name" 
HeaderText="File Name" NavigateUrl="~/Download.aspx/test" />
```

Comment: If your wanting to call a method you might want to use a Link button and catch its on click event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclick.aspx

Comment: What are you going to do with the customer info after you download it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to invoke a method via a link button click action. You can use PostbackUrl property and set it to the your method using following trick. But to do it you have to mark your method as WebMethod so that it get exposed as a web service method.

```
[WebMethod]  
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public string SomeMethod(string value)
{
    // your logic goes here
}
```

**----- EDIT-------------**

```
[WebMethod]  
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public static string SomeMethod(string value)
{
    // your logic goes here
}
```

in web.config :

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
```

Now call your method like this. Put this url in your postbackurl property of linkbutton.

http://yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx/SomeMethod?value=somevalue

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This gives me enough info to move on. But, the hyperlink is created on a field of type hyperlink in a gridview control. There is no postbackurl property. Should I use the Navigateurl property that is available, instead. Many thanks.

Comment: If it's a hyperlink then you can use NavigateUrl property.

Comment: Hi, I created a public method in a web form and exposed it as you have suggested. The method i snot being executed. What might be the problem?

Comment: I missed... the method have to be Static. Updated the code above.

Comment: I tried that. Still does not work. I have updated the question with the source from the aspx page.